# Flashing firmware in ft232rl

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, ftdi

I am new with arduino and hardwares at all and I am having some problems in a project where I want to assemble the head tracker device from this project https://git.iem.at/DIY/MrHeadTracker/wikis/mrht-bno055 ... They use an Arduino pro mini for data processing (with a .ino sketch provided by them), an Arduino USB 2 Serial micro for connecting the pro mino to the pc, and a sensor BNO055 by Adafruit which provides orientation data. I am using the same hardwares instead of the USB converter that in my case is the ft232rl by FTDI. The step I am having problem is the one where I have to flash the HIDUINO firmware (they provide an .hex file) so I can use the whole thing as a MIDI device.

The point is that I just don't understand if I have to overwrite the pro mini's serial firmware or the usb converter's and how it's the correct way to do it, mainly because I can't find examples with the usb converter I have and every new reference I read makes me think of one possibility. In the first link they suggest reading the information in https://github.com/ddiakopoulos/hiduino/wiki which presents 2 methods: DFU method, that tells I need Atmel Flip software for Windows and ISP method, that I don't know if is my case because I can't find out if my ftdi board is an ISP programmer. I've read about it and in other references also, but I am still not sure about what I have to do.
I hope that someone can help! And sorry for the basic doubts...
Thanks!

Comment: The arduino USB2serial has an AVR that can be flashed with new firmware. Your FTDI device does not have MCU that can be re-programmed.

Comment: @Craig, actually, you can make some changes to the FTDI adapter ... http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Utilities.htm#FT2xxR

Comment: @Craig if that is the case, it means I can't use the board for this application because it can't be reprogrammed or i just don't need to overwrite any firmware because there's nothing to be reprogrammed? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @jsotola Which would be the right section of the link you sent? Thank for your answer!

Comment: @Enzor, I do not know if any sections apply to you ... it is unclear what you are trying to do. .... the ftdi chip is just a USB to serial adapter

Comment: @jsotola sorry for that... I actually have problemas to explain the problem too... but what I am trying to find out is how to do this step "Flash the USB2Serial interface according to https://github.com/ddiakopoulos/hiduino/wiki.
You can use the provided MrHeadTracker.hex file (HiduinoFirmware directory).", which makes me think I have to do something in my usb to serial conterver, the ftdi, because is the board I am using to substitute the Arduino USB2 serial from their project...

Comment: @jsotola The main sketch (.ino) is already uploaded in the pro mini... the device is designed to be a class-compliant MIDI, including the way the code ( https://git.iem.at/DIY/MrHeadTracker/tree/master/Arduino/MrHeadTrackerBNO055Switchable )is written that uses MIDI library... Here's antoher thing they say that makes me think it's all about the usb conv "To enable plug-and-play support without any additional
software, the Arduino USB2Serial converter is used.
Its Atmel 16u2 micro-controller can be programmed to
appear as a class-compliant USB-MIDI device using the
HIDUINO library"